# Weird characters when reading a file on Android

Tags: android, json, io

I am saving a JSON file to a private directory on Android. The problem is that when I read the file, the text is padded with weird characters at the end and I'm not sure why this is happening.

**Log:**

> E/WRITTEN(25254):
> {"sex":"MALE","activity_factor":1.2,"weight":0,"height":180.0,"weight_loss_goal":0,"age":30}
>
> E/StartActivity(25254): RELAUNCH 07-03
>
> E/READ(25254):
> {"sex":"MALE","activity_factor":1.2,"weight":0,"height":180.0,"weight_loss_goal":0,"age":30}????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????..(this goes on and on and on)

**FileWrite i/o code:**

```
public class FileUtil
{
    public static void writeToFile ( Context context, String filename, String text, int mode ) throws IOException
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try
        {
            fos = context.openFileOutput ( filename, mode );
            fos.write ( text.getBytes () );
            
            Log.e("WRITTEN",text);
        }
        catch ( FileNotFoundException e )
        {
            throw e;
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            if ( fos != null )
            {
                try
                {
                    fos.close ();
                }
                catch ( IOException e )
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static String readFromFile ( Context context, String fileName ) throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder ( "" );
        try
        {
            byte [] buffer = new byte [1024];
            fis = context.openFileInput ( fileName );

            while ( fis.read ( buffer ) != -1 )
            {
                content.append ( new String ( buffer ) );
            }
        }
        catch ( FileNotFoundException e )
        {
            throw e;
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            if ( fis != null )
            {
                try
                {
                    fis.close ();
                }
                catch ( IOException e )
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }
            }
        }
        Log.e("READ",content.toString ());
        return content.toString ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what is "mode" in this case? And did the file exist beforehand? It's a bad idea to use String.getBytes without specifying an encoding, by the way.

Comment: Try using `text.getBytes("UTF-8")` and `new String(buffer, "UTF-8")`.

Comment: I didn't know that, I was following the example on the Android Developer page. Despite that, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming that the entire 1024 byte buffer has been filled by the read, which would only be the case if the file is at least that long.  Evidently it isn't, so you are displaying a lot of uninitialized memory beyond where the read stopped.

The return value of the version of read() which you are using is the number of bytes read.  Save that in a variable instead of only checking for failure, and then only attempt to use that many bytes of the buffer.

Comment: Should have seen that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

While reading the file use new InputStreamReader(is, **"windows-1252")**. That should sovle the issue.